# C++ char definition from binary string and overflow

Tags: c++, types

I have a datatype that's more or less a character array. Each space in the array holds a char, which, as per my understanding, is a single byte (8 bits) of information. I need to be able to specify the char value through a binary string... for instance

```
char someChar = char(0b00110011);
```

What I don't understand is why the max value I can specify is 0b0XXXXXXX, where I have to leave that MSB set to zero. If I try setting the char like so

```
char someChar = char(0b11111111);
```

I get a decimal value: -2147483648, which looks very much like overflow. So I don't really get what's going on here. If I call the sizeof() operator on char, I get an answer of 1 (one byte). Doesn't that mean that I either get 0-255 if the char is unsigned, or -128-127 if the char is signed? Any advice/input would be appreciated.

In response to most of the comments -- I converted it to an int before printing it out:
   std::cerr << int(someChar)

Thanks to all for the thorough explanations :)

Comment: When you say "I get -2147483648", what is the actual code that takes `someChar` and produces `-2147483648`?

Comment: `char` by itself is _signed_ which means the MSB is used to mark a negative number. That you get such a large number must be because of a cast to a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `char` by itself can be signed *or* unsigned. It's up to the implementation. (In this respect, it's unlike other integer types.)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg char can be unsigned. Also, two's compliment is a bit different than a sign bit.

Comment: @aix Correct, but I can't remember ever seeing a compiler treat `char` as unsigned.

Comment: Your code isn't standard C++. Binary literals are at best some compiler extension.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: IIRC IBM's xlC compiler for AIX is one such example.

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1 by definition. It does not always mean it is 8 bits. (Although it almost always is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-2147483648 in binary is 10000000 00000000 00000000 01111111.

When you declare you `char` in binary, you compiler interprets it as a `signed char`, which is the case for the most compilers. The leftmost bit is interpreted as the sign bit.

Upon conversion to `int`, the bit pattern of the *value* is copied, therefore the seven rightmost bits, and the sign bit is moved to the MSB of the 32-bit block.

You have two main problems here :

- First, it seems that you except `someChar` to be unsigned. If that's the case, you should tell it to your compiler : `unsigned char someChar = unsigned char(0b11111111);`
- Second, the way you put it to the console (which is unknown to us) apparently involves a conversion to `int`. If it's not needed, there is likely a way to print `someChar` for what it is really, i.e. a `signed char`.

Comment: I believe -2147483648 in 32 bit twos-compliment is 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000.

Comment: A standard conversion from `char` to `int` won't do anything like that; a widening conversion will preserve the value, whether it's signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is signed *in this case*, so setting the top bit will give a negative value. Use `unsigned char` if you don't want to worry about positive/negative values.

As for the negative integer value - please show how you're converting/displaying the char.

---

NB. You can use `signed char` or `unsigned char` to tell the compiler explicitly what you want.

Comment: `char` may or may not be signed, according to the C++ standard.  In this case, it looks like Pris's compiler treats `char` as signed.